# Xlib.h not found when building graphviz on Mac OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion)

Tags: x11, graphviz, homebrew, osx-mountain-lion

When using homebrew to install graphviz, the script gets to the point of "Making install in tkstubs" and then throws the following fatal error:

```
In file included from tkStubLib.c:15:
/usr/include/tk.h:78:11: fatal error: 'X11/Xlib.h' file not found
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
```

I have installed XQuartz as X11 has been dropped in Mountain Lion, but I'm unsure if it is installed correctly. The location of Xlib.h is:

```
/opt/X11/include/X11/Xlib.h
```

There are also two symlinks to /opt/X11, they are:

```
/usr/X11
/usr/X11R6
```

Does this look like the correct setup to you? I've never dealt with X11 or XQuartz until yesterday.

Cheers.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to tell the `tkstubs` build (and possibly other bits in the package as well) to look for headers in `/opt/X11/include`; this is not on the standard include path.

Usually this is achieved by passing `-I/opt/X11/include` as an additional compiler flag, the method to do so is however dependent on the build system.

For reasonably modern `configure` scripts, the best approach is to pass it in the environment variable `CPPFLAGS`; if the package uses another build system or this doesn't work for another reason, then you need to look at the `Makefile` in the build directory.

Comment: `CPPFLAGS` is for preprocessor flags -- the C++ compiler invocation is expected to respect these. C only flags go in `CFLAGS`, C++ only flags in `CXXFLAGS`.

Comment: Ah yes of course... Too early in the morning for me to think I guess... :)

Comment: Perfect. I added this to the ruby script: ENV.append 'CFLAGS', '-I/opt/X11/include' and it installed fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 121):

After installing XQuartz you may add a symlink to your X11 installation folder by just entering

```
ln -s /opt/X11/include/X11 /usr/local/include/X11
```

in terminal. That will fix the problem as well without changing any ruby script.

Comment: and then shows `ld: library not found for -lX11`, how to fix?

Answer (score 29):

You can enter in your shell before the compile/link (or brew) command:

```
export CPPFLAGS=-I/opt/X11/include
```

The export line will tell the compile/linker to look in /opt/X11/include for the X11 include files

Comment: same here. worked on Mavericks. in my case path was like this:
`export CPPFLAGS=-I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers;`

Answer (score 7):

Had the same issue and running this command on terminal

```
xcode-select --install
```

worked for me. Run this command after installing [xQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org/).

Comment: Worked for me too as well. macOS Sierra 10.12.6 (16G29), Python 2.7.13 installed using `pyenv install 2.7.13`.

Answer (score 6):

If you need this to work in your CMake builds:

```
if(APPLE)
   include_directories(AFTER "/opt/X11/include")
endif()
```

That worked well for me.

Answer (score 2):

I got it to install by copying the x11 header file directory to the /opt/local/include directory.  Probably not the best way to work around it but quick and easy.

Answer (score 2):

I found this thread while trying to compile ffmpeg from source on OS X. I needed `--enable-x11grab` and the homebrew build does not support this option.

I had XQuartz installed already but I kept getting errors from `./configure`: `ERROR: Xlib not found`. I thought the answers here would solve my problem, but they did not!

So, if anyone is ever in the same boat, my solution was this:

I opened up the generated `config.log` and found lots of errors referring to various includes and header files, including X11/Xlib.h - this is misleading. At the very bottom of the logfile was the key, `pkg-config` was complaining about looking for `xbc.pc`, and requested that it be put on the path. However, the error message that is displayed on the terminal says nothing about `pkg-config` or `xbc`!

The solution is to add to your `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable. Mine was nonexistent, so I just did `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/X11/lib/pkgconfig/` (the folder where I found `xbc.pc`).

I reran `configure` and everything worked like a charm!

### TL;DR: check config.log - don't trust the terminal output!

Comment: Thanks so much for this post. I was running on OSX and the underlying problem was that it was running clang instead of gcc. I would never have thought to look into the log file without this comment. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Since the make file is looking for X11/xlib.h i.e., it is looking for X11 folder in the current directory, one way to solve this problem is to simply copy the /opt/X11/include/X11 directory to the directory that contains make file.