# Get error when try to install PIL

Tags: python, installation, python-imaging-library

I try to install PIL but get errors, what should I do?

```
$ Command
Result
------------
$ pip install PIL

Collecting PIL
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PIL
--------------------------------------------------------------------
$ pip install PIL  --allow-unverified PIL --allow-all-external

DEPRECATION: --allow-all-external has been deprecated and will be removed in the future. Due to changes in the repository protocol, it no longer has any effect.
DEPRECATION: --allow-unverified has been deprecated and will be removed in the future. Due to changes in the repository protocol, it no longer has any effect.
Collecting PIL
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PIL
```

Comment: what system ? On Linux Mint you can use `apt-get` to install `python-pil` or `python-pillow`

Answer (score 168, accepted):

You could try using [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/) instead, which is a PIL fork:

```
pip install Pillow
```

To import use:

```
from PIL import Image
```

Comment: Why does this work, it seems unintuitive not to use `pip install PIL` like with most python libraries?

Comment: @stevec https://stackoverflow.com/a/30548135/7341011

Comment: if you are using Visual Studio Code, then restarting after the pip install Pillow should work.

Answer (score 25):

The library `PIL` is in `Pillow`. Try this:

```
$ pip install Pillow
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is a better way than this. But this may work as described in the documentation:

http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/.

Download the source kit and extract it. Once extracted, do the following as described in the kit.

```
    $ tar xvfz Imaging-1.1.7.tar.gz
    $ cd Imaging-1.1.7
    $ python setup.py install
```

Comment: In file included from _imagingtk.c:19:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/tk.h:78:11: fatal error: 
      'X11/Xlib.h' file not found
#       include <X11/Xlib.h>
                ^
1 error generated.
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

Comment: See if any of the solutions here solve the problem. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465258/xlib-h-not-found-when-building-graphviz-on-mac-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion