# Why is the argument used with pip install sometimes different to the argument used by import?

Tags: python, pip

For many python libraries, the argument used with `import` is the same as the one used to install the library with pip.

E.g.

```sh
pip install numpy
pip install scipy
pip install pandas
```

correspond to

```py
import numpy
import scipy
import pandas
```

but this pattern doesn't seem to work for all libraries. E.g. (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41326447/5783745)):

```sh
pip install Pillow
```

is required to get this to succeed

```py
import PIL
```

Based on the pattern in the first examples, I would have expected `pip install PIL` to install `PIL`, but instead we use `pip install Pillow`. Why is this and how does this work?

Comment: from Pillow docs: ```Pillow is the friendly PIL fork by Alex Clark and Contributors. PIL is the Python Imaging Library by Fredrik Lundh and Contributors.```. Package itself is called Pillow, but it is actually PIL fork. Thats why you import PIL.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54599368/7976758

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, what you import is usually the module name. For example, your package might be developed in the following hierarchy:

```
MyLib
- __init__.py
- my_script1.py
- my_script2.py
```

However, when you make your library as a "package" available in `pip`, usually you will need to prepare your `setup.py` file, which will be automatically run when people use `pip install` to install your package.

The `setup.py` can be something like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup(
  name = 'YOURPACKAGENAME',         # How you named your package folder (MyLib)
  packages = ['YOURPACKAGENAME'],   # Chose the same as "name"
  version = '0.1',      # Start with a small number and increase it with every change you make
  license='MIT',        # Chose a license from here: https://help.github.com/articles/licensing-a-repository
  description = 'TYPE YOUR DESCRIPTION HERE',   # Give a short description about your library
  author = 'YOUR NAME',                   # Type in your name
  author_email = 'your.email@domain.com',      # Type in your E-Mail
  url = 'https://github.com/user/reponame',   # Provide either the link to your github or to your website
  download_url = 'https://github.com/user/reponame/archive/v_01.tar.gz',    # I explain this later on
  keywords = ['SOME', 'MEANINGFULL', 'KEYWORDS'],   # Keywords that define your package best
  install_requires=[            # I get to this in a second
          'validators',
          'beautifulsoup4',
      ],
  classifiers=[
    'Development Status :: 3 - Alpha',      # Chose either "3 - Alpha", "4 - Beta" or "5 - Production/Stable" as the current state of your package
    'Intended Audience :: Developers',      # Define that your audience are developers
    'Topic :: Software Development :: Build Tools',
    'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',   # Again, pick a license
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',      #Specify which pyhton versions that you want to support
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6',
  ],
)
```

Therefore, in the above example, people who install your package via `pip` should run `pip install YOURPACKAGENAME`. After that, they need to run `import MyLib` in the code.

TD; DL:

What you import is a module name, but what you installed via `pip` is the name of the package, they can be different. But usually, I would say that I like people to use the same name for both to avoid any confusing.

Ref:
https://medium.com/@joel.barmettler/how-to-upload-your-python-package-to-pypi-65edc5fe9c56

Comment: Thanks, great explanation! Is there a way to find the package name (to use with pip)? E.g. I need to run `import inception5h`, but `ERROR: No matching distribution found for inception5h`. With `PIL` I was able to find the package name by googling, and thankfully others had had the same question. But with `inception5h` I cannot find the package name easily. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Maybe there is, but I don't know honestly. I met the same issue before, I would say just google it :) Try googling `install sklearn` you will know what I mean.