# how can install library pil in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

when i want to install pil on python by using Bycharm tell me error
my OS it window10 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myV4E.jpg)
this more detail about my problem

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PIL

my python version it:
Python 3.9.4 (tags/v3.9.4:1f2e308, Apr  6 2021, 13:40:21) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

pip --version
pip 20.2.3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgTrB.jpg)

Comment: Please don't post images of terminal output. Simply copy/paste it into oyur question

Comment: Try `pip install pillow`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get error when try to install PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41326387/get-error-when-try-to-install-pil)

Comment: @FlyingTeller no its not for me and i try but same problem

Comment: @FlyingTeller know i want to install pylab and get the same problem  ) >pip install pylab
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pylab (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pylab

Comment: Which package do you mean by `pylab`. [There does not seem to be a package with that name on pypi](https://pypi.org/search/?q=pylab)

Comment: @FlyingTeller please could you tell me what th problem with command (cv2.imshow("trees",img)) form library openCv ,,,,,,,,, when i want to show final result the window disappear I sure the code its right